# mysql query cache hit rate hitting 100%

Tags: mysql, query-cache

I am wondering if this is an issue, like if its a good or bad thing. Is having the query cache hit rate hitting 100% often bad?

http://gameboxtools.com/uploads/imagehost/20120928064614983.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good thing to have a high hit rate on the query cache. It means that subsequent calls to the same query are being answered directly from the cache and thus are faster. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache.html).